# What is the number of this small 1x1 part?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I tried to find the number of this small part. I need it to create the two towers of Notre Dame.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That's [49668 Plate Special 1 x 1 with Tooth](https://rebrickable.com/parts/49668/plate-special-1-x-1-with-tooth/).

[image: Part render]

Comment: super, thank you